# How can I remove this strange bath vanity light?

Tags: light, vanity

I want to change   the lighting above our bathroom vanity but i perplexed with the existing   strange fixture. (*see Image below*)

I am at a loss how to remove it.  I do not see any type of markings or model number.

Any help would be appreciated

[image]

Comment: be very careful when handling the fixture ..... there may be LIVE AC on the exposed wire connection or even on the heatsink

Comment: @jsotola if the light switch is on, then yes the two black wires will be live. but the power is DC, and probably between 12 and 40 volts.

Comment: @david yes, the LED wil have 12-40 volts across it, but it could be 120V relative to the metal frame of the light.

Comment: OP what are you trying to do exactly? Change the "bulb"? Get the fixture off the wall? Fix a defective light?

Answer (score 2):

That looks to be a built in LED light. No (easy) way to replace the light when it burns out, you are supposed to get a whole new light. This is a newish trend in lighting that I'm not in favor of. Its great for the manufactures, not for consumers or the environment.

If you are handy with electronics and know how to solder, you *can* replace it.

The white chip on the bottom of the large heat sink, that is the LED. Desolder it and see if there are any identification marks on it. If not  you will have to figure out what new LED chip to get from the power supply in the light. Look at the voltage and the wattage it supplies.

Assuming you can deduce the correct replacement chip, *and* you found a source to buy one. Then you will need to apply a thermal paste to the new chip before you screw it back down to the heat sink. Last resolder the electrical connections.

Is it worth it? Sadly, probably not.
Just get a new light fixture.

Comment: With all the led fixtures I have had that failed it has been the driver that was the failed component, that light may be able to be replaced with a newer style corn lamp by installing an Edison lamp base, the newer LED's are much more efficient and smaller than they were 2 , 3 years ago. I would look for DLC listed lamps these have a 5 year warranty to be listed. I just purchased some lamps that look like regular bulbs 16w at 1600 lumens or 100w equivlent, the make smaller wattage ones but that would be a way to save the fixture.

Comment: LEDs basically never fail, and that,s why it's silly to socket them.   The problem is in the driver.  Putting a DC voltmeter on the two wires will prove that out.

Comment: @EdBeal's right.  My bathroom lamp is on its third driver (one replaced under warranty; I managed to squeeze  a different brand in recently.  It's a common problem.  If replacing the fitting means a lot of work (electrical or decorating) see if you can get at the driver, which will have specifications or at least a make/model and try to track down a replacement or equivalent that will fit

Answer (score 0):

It would probably be easiest to change the entire fixture.   Keep that in mind as an option.

If you just want to change the "bulb" (not the LED chip, but the whole heat sink assembly in your picture) you would still need to remove the whole fixture from the wall, completely disassemble it, and buy lamp parts from a lamp part web site and change it all out to a standard light bulb socket, then put in a screw-in LED bulb.

Lots of possibly bad assumptions here: 1) the wire coming through the top of the metal dome in your picture is 120V, 2) you can find a combination socket and bulb that will fit inside the lamp shade that this is designed for, 3) it's worth all the hassle vs buying a whole new fixture.

Something LIKE this picture.  You'd need to see how the current thing is held to the dome, and maybe adapt with new threaded rods, nuts, etc (all from lamp parts shop)

[image]